# How to use Ruby gsub with regex to do partial string substitution

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub, string-substitution

I have a pipe delimited file which has a line

```
H||CUSTCHQH2H||PHPCCIPHP|1010032000|28092017|25001853||||
```

I want to substitute the date (28092017) with a regex "[0-9]{8}" if the first character is "H"

I tried the following example to test my understanding where Im trying to subtitute "a" with "i".

```
str = "|123||a|"
str.gsub /\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|/, "\|\\1\|\|\\1\|i\|"
```

But this is giving o/p as 

`"|123||123|i|"`

Any clue how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace the first occurrence of 8 digits inside pipes if a string starts with `H` using

```
s = "H||CUSTCHQH2H||PHPCCIPHP|1010032000|28092017|25001853||||"
p s.gsub(/\A(H.*?\|)[0-9]{8}(?=\|)/, '\100000000')
# or
p s.gsub(/\AH.*?\|\K[0-9]{8}(?=\|)/, '00000000')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/UNuvPB). Here, the value is replaced with 8 zeros.

**Pattern details**

- `\A` - start of string (`^` is the start of a line in Ruby)
- `(H.*?\|)` - Capturing group 1 (you do not need it when using the variation with `\K`): `H` and then any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `[0-9]{8}` - eight digits
- `(?=\|)` - the next char must be `|`, but it is not added to the match value since it is a positive lookahead that does not consume text.

The `\1` in the first `gsub` is a *replacement backreference* to the value in Group 1.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew   Could you please elaborate "(?=\|)". Why is it not added to the match value

Comment: @Navi *it is not added to the match value since it is a positive lookahead that does not consume text* -  "*lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.*", see more about [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).